# Month to date sum SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I am trying to create a daily figure and month to date total in SQL server.

```
    DATE                             Name         Figure             MTD
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000          Luke          10              0.000000
    2017-09-02 00:00:00.000          Luke          10              0.000000
    2017-09-03 00:00:00.000          Luke          10              0.000000
    2017-09-04 00:00:00.000          Luke          10              0.000000
```

Basically i want the mtd to show 40 even if i limit to just one day like below.

```
    DATE                     Name               Figure              MTD
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 Luke                  10                40
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: How is MTD= 40 if all the values in your table (MTD column) are all 0? You just want to hard code 40?

Comment: no, the month to date is calculated from the total of the daily figure for the month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample code in MS Sql Server is given below:

```
 CREATE TABLE #Order(ORDERDATE datetime,SalespersonName VARCHAR(30),  DailyFigure int)

INSERT INTO #Order VALUES
    ('2017-09-01 00:00:00.000','Luke',10),              
    ('2017-09-02 00:00:00.000','Luke',10),              
    ('2017-09-03 00:00:00.000','Luke',10),              
    ('2017-09-04 00:00:00.000','Luke',10);   

    SELECT * FROM #Order 

    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT ORDERDATE, SalespersonName,DailyFigure, SUM(DailyFigure) OVER(PARTITION BY SalesPersonName, MONTH(OrderDate)) AS MTD
    FROM #Order) as r
    WHERE ORDERDATE = '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have similar working code to this but basically as soon as i limit to display one day with a where clause, the month to date is then only summed from one day e.g.  ORDER DATE              Salesperson Name    Daily Figure       MTD
    2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 Luke                  10                10

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, I have updated the answer accordingly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT MIN(ORDERDATE), 
        SalespersonName,
        AVG(DailyFigure) DailyFigure,
        SUM(DailyFigure) MTD
   FROM Order
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)